# Not able to select instance memory class less than m4 series

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

My AWS account was disabled and rds (mysql) was terminated after taking the snapshot, When I am trying to restore RDS from the snapshot I am not able to select a memory class lower than M4 series.

Had anyone faced this issue before? Any suggestions on lowering the memory class series?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wanted an earlier generation? Is there a particular instance type you wanted?

Comment: Cost, M4 series I cant afford.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the [Amazon RDS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/pricing/) does not show any General Purposes instances prior to the M5 generation. If you can get M4, then that's great!

For us-east, a `db.m5.large` is 17.1c/hour.

According to the [Amazon RDS previous generation](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/previous-generation/) page, pricing is:

- `db.m4.large` 17.5c/hour
- `db.m3.large` 18.5c/hour
- `db.m2.xlarge` (smallest possible) is 33c/hour
- `db.m1.large` 46c/hour (`db.m1.small` is 11c/hour, but that's *really* old)

So, the older-generation db instance types are actually *more expensive* than an M5 db instance.

If this remains too expensive for you, some options are:

- Turn off the Amazon RDS database when it is not in use, or
- Launch an Amazon EC2 instance and install/run the database yourself, or
- Move to **Amazon Aurora Serverless**, where "you only pay for the database capacity, storage, and I/O your database consumes when it is active"